# How to scrape the links, titles, authors and timestamps for the 10 articles here? Soup output looks different from browser

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to get the **links**, **titles**, **authors** and **timestamps** of the 10 articles that are on this webpage: https://www.investing.com/equities/micron-tech-news

At the time of writing,

The first article is the link is "https://www.investing.com/news/economy/take-five-swap-lines-to-the-rescue-2117042",

the title is "Take Five: Swap lines to the rescue",

the author is "By Reuters"

and the time stamp is "22 hours ago".

There are a total of 10 articles on the page. However, when I try to run beautifulsoup4 with requests, I get a bunch of articles that are not supposed to be there before the first correct article appears.

And a bunch of junk articles appear at the end as well, in the end only 4 of the links appear while the others are not supposed to be there.

I don't know why the webpage is loading like this. How can I go about doing what I want?

I'm using the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

header = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}

link = "https://www.investing.com/equities/micron-tech/"

linklist = []
r = requests.get(link, headers=header)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html")
links = soup.findAll("a", { "class" : "img" }) 
titles = soup.findAll("a", { "class" : "title" })
details = soup.findAll("span",{"class":"articleDetails"}) #contains the author and time stamp

for i in range(len(links)):
    print(links[i]['href']) #links
    print(titles[i]['title']) #titles
    # print(details[i]['span']) #doesnt work
    print(details[i])  #author and time stamp
```

As you can see I'm having 2 problems, firstly, the articles don't appear to be the same as on the website, secondly, I can't access the details which show the author and the timestamp, when i try to do details[i]['span'] I get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact it seems that there are also articles on the top of the page so you may need to look at the second parent `div` with `class=mediumTitle1` for instance. Also for the elements with class `articleDetails` sometimes they are `div` sometimes they are `span` so you can use `find(class_="articleDetails").findNext("span")` to extract the author to deal with both :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get(
    "https://www.investing.com/equities/micron-tech-news",
    headers= {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36"}
)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser").find_all("div",{"class":"mediumTitle1"})[1]

result = []
for i in soup.find_all("article"):
    data = {}
    data["link"] = i.find("a", {"class":"img"})["href"]
    data["title"] = i.find("a", {"class":"title"}).text
    details = i.find(class_="articleDetails").find_all("span")
    data["author"] = details[0].text
    data["date"] = details[1].text
    result.append(data)

print(result)
```

Comment: hey what about the date?